# Left Outer Joining Tables with Multiple Property Keys

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I have two tables 'case' and 'case_char'.

**case**

```
case_id | status | date  
    1   | closed | 01/01/2014  
    2   | open   | 02/01/2014
```

**case_char**

```
case_id | property_key |  value  
   1    | email        | xx@xx.com  
   1    | phone        | 1234567  
   2    | email        | x2@xx.com  
   2    | phone        | 987654  
   2    | issue        | Unhappy
```

Say I want to return the 'issue' for each case. Not all cases have issues so I will need to do a left outer join. Unfortunately it is not working for me, it is returning only cases with the 'issue' characteristic. I need it to return all cases regardless of whether the 'issue' characteristic exists for a case in the case_char table.

Below is an example of the way I have written the code ( bearing in mind I am using an Oracle DB).

Could any of you whizzes help a brother out?

```
SELECT   c.case_id, char.value  
FROM  case c, case_char char  
WHERE c.case_id = char.case_id (+)  
AND char.property_key = 'issue'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I ended up getting around it with SELECT   c.case_id, char.value  
FROM  case c, case_char char  
WHERE c.case_id = char.case_id (+)  
AND char.property_key (+) = 'issue'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a Join(+) to your property key as below:

```
SELECT   C.CASE_ID, CHAR.VALUE  
FROM     CASE C, CASE_CHAR CHAR  
WHERE    
         C.CASE_ID = CHAR.CASE_ID (+)  
         AND
         CHAR.PROPERTY_KEY(+) = 'ISSUE';
                           ^
                           |
```

Comment: I had already answered my own question but for others looking at this query, yours was identical to mine. I appreciate you taking the time to look at it!

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use an explicit join, and put the `property_key` in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT c.case_id, char.value
FROM case AS c
LEFT JOIN case_char AS char ON c.case_id = char.case_id AND char.property_key = 'issue'
```

I'm not very familiar with the syntax for implicit out joins. My guess is you need to put `(+)` after `char.property_key = 'issue'` to keep it from filtering out the null rows.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want 1 row per case regardless of whether or not it has an issue, but all the issues for each case?

If that's what you want, something close to this should work (I'm a SQL Server guy, so I'm not totally sure that this will work with Oracle).

```
SELECT
 c.case_id
,char.value
FROM case AS c
LEFT JOIN case_char AS char
ON
    c.case_id = char.case_id
AND char.property_key = 'issue'
```

Basically, we've moved the filter logic to the `join` condition, otherwise the `WHERE` clause will filter out anything that's not an 'issue'.

Does that answer your question?